# How to use XPages Java code to set valid method of input control inside a custom control?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, xpages

Ok, this is a weird one.

In XPages my dataSource is a Java Object.  A Managed bean or PageController.  I'm using bootstrap via the Ext. Library.

What I'd like to do is keep all my validation code inside my Java Object rather then attaching anything to the control on the XPage.  Inside the java object I can add any error messages via:
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage

So any errors can by showed via an  control.

BUT what I don't know how to do is to target an individual control if I wanted to send a message to a specific  (singular) control.

Realistically what I'd love to be able to is use this example for a bootstrap field custom control : http://www.bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/reusableFields.xsp

and from my Java class set the isValid method so the bootstrap field is rendered red via the has-error style.

Any advice on how to get to the the isValid for an input control inside a custom control or even an alternative method to let me validate via java but control the field styling would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What I do is using a custom validator for the component. For instance,

```
<xp:this.validators>
    <xp:customValidator validate="#{javascript:controller.validateDuration(this)}"></xp:customValidator>
</xp:this.validators>
```

In my controller class:

```
public void validateDuration(UIComponent source) {
    // Do my checks...
    // If fails,
    BeanUtils.setControlInvalid(source, "Format Error at date time!");
}
```

BeanUtils methods to invalidate a specific component and generate a validation error message:

```
public static void setControlInvalid(UIComponent editableComponent, String message) {
    if(StringUtil.isEmpty(message) || editableComponent==null) return;

    if(editableComponent instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
        ((EditableValueHolder) editableComponent).setValid(false);
        postFacesMessage(editableComponent, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message);
    }

}

public static void postFacesMessage(UIComponent component, Severity severity, String msg) {
    if(StringUtil.isEmpty(msg) || component==null) return;

    FacesContext fc=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    FacesMessage message=new FacesMessage(severity, msg, msg);
    fc.addMessage(component.getClientId(fc), message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Serdar.  I'm digesting this.  I'm not exactly sure how to use this with the edit control living inside a custom control.  I guess I'd have to computer the ID in some fashion but I'm not sure.  I do think I might have an alternate method that I'm experimenting with now.

Answer (score 1):

Any UIComponent has a `setValid(boolean)` method. All controls also have a `binding` property, which can be used to bind that component to a Java object, e.g. a property in your bean.

However, if your custom control is used multiple times, you can't use that, because all instances would be trying to bind to the same bean property.

But, with a bit of cunning thought, it's possible to take advantage of the same concept. If your bean has a `Map<String, Component> myCunningBindings`, you could add a collection of bindings dynamically using this code in the loaded property:

```
<this.loaded><![CDATA[${javascript:myBean.getMyCunningBindings().put(compositeData.fieldMapping, this);
return "";}]]>
</xp:this.loaded>
```

So the first line of the code gets the map and adds an element. That element has a value (the component itself) and a label. For the label, we get the field mapping that you're also likely to be passing in via `compositeData`. Finally, we return true.

Your bean that does the validation should know where it's saving it to, so you should be able to calculate the field mapping that was passed into compositeData, which will be the key you need to look for in the Map. And from there, you have the component to call setValid(false) on.

Comment: Jesse Gallagher got there before me https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/073D97410CE1F89785257D0B00773F4A

Comment: Thanks Paul and Jesse.  Very interesting.  I'm digesting that as well.  Though I am starting to wonder if I really even need the component and can't just get the same result without it.