# Xpages: Validation using java bean with multiple instances of a custom control

Tags: xpages, custom-controls

I have a custom control for an editable field, and validation is done via a java bean. I want to set the isValid() property to set bootstrap styling like so:

[image]

However, this does not work if I place the cc on a page more than once, because I am searching on the component's ID to set the Valid property.

I need to either compute the id of the field in the CC, or do something else like this [post describes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847441/how-to-use-xpages-java-code-to-set-valid-method-of-input-control-inside-a-custom).

I believe I can compute the ID of the text field like so:

```
<xp:inputText
                id="${javascript:compositeData.fieldName}"
                type="text"
                loaded="${!empty compositeData.placeholder}"
                required="${compositeData.required}"
                disableClientSideValidation="true">
                <xp:this.attrs>
                    <xp:attr
                        name="placeholder"
                        value="${compositeData.placeholder}" />
                </xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:this.binding><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName]}]]></xp:this.binding>
            </xp:inputText>
```

However, there are a few places where I need to compute the component, such as

```
<xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:"form-group" + (getComponent("inputText1").isValid() ? "" : " has-error" )}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
```

I have to replace the "inputText1" with the computed ID, but cannot figure out how to do so.

Is there a better/easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you not use the compositeData.fieldName everywhere you reference the id?

```
<xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:"form-group" + (getComponent(compositeData.fieldName).isValid() ? "" : " has-error" )}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
```

Comment: Howard, that was exactly what I was trying to do but could not get the syntax right. Thanks for your answer!